# How to convert global_invocation_id to clip space coordinates? (To convert depth buffer to world space position)

Tags: coordinate-systems, webgpu, wgsl

I am writing a compute shader that runs some function for every pixel in a framebuffer. To simplify this question, I'm using a workgroup size of 1.

```rust
@compute
@workgroup_size(1, 1)
fn main(@builtin(global_invocation_id) gid: vec3u) { ... }
```

Dispatching via `pass.dispatch_workgroups(screen_width, screen_height, 1)`.

That means my `main` function is called with `gid = (x, y, 1)` for all `0 <= x < screen_width` and `0 <= y < screen_height`. Specifically, the bottom right pixel will have `gid = (screen_width - 1, screen_height - 1, 1)`, right?

I have a depth buffer from a previous pass. I want to convert those depth values to world coordinates. And for that I need to convert `gid` into clip space coordinates. Here is what I want to do:

```rust
let depth = textureLoad(depth_buffer, gid.xy, 0);
let clip_space = ?????;
let world_space_hc = inverse_view_proj_matrix * vec4(clip_space, depth, 1.0);
let world_space = world_space_hc.xyz / world_space_hc.w;
```

What to write in place of `????` is my question! My naive approach was:

```rust
let uv = vec2f(gid.xy) / screen_size;
let clip_space = vec2(uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y) * 2.0 - 1.0;
```

The second line is correct, I think. And this seems to work. But I am worried that this is slightly incorrect. In particular, the bottom right pixel with `(screen_width - 1, screen_height - 1)` will NOT map to `(1, 1)` with this algorithm. And that seems wrong.

I've been reading the WebGPU spec (in particular the [coordinate system](https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/#coordinate-systems) [rasterization](https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/#rasterization) parts), but I'm still not 100% clear. I *think* that corner pixels "look along" edges of the view frustum exactly. This would mean the correct conversion is:

```rust
let uv = vec2f(gid.xy) / (screen_size - vec2f(1.0);
```

Is that correct?

A third option I could see is:

```rust
let uv = (vec2f(gid.xy) + vec2f(0.5)) / screen_size;
```

I'd greatly appreciate an answer finally explaining this to me.

Comment: From experimenting a bit, it actually looks like the last option (`+ 0.5)` is the correct one. But I can't explain why, so I'm still really looking for an answer. (In RenderDoc it looks like the top left pixel gets a `@builtin(position)` of `(0.5, 0.5, ..)`. Of course that's just shows the value in the Vulkan implementation, so I'm not sure how much that information really tells me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easiler to visualize texture coordinates (And clip space coordinates) with a small example. Imagine you have a 3x2 texture (or canvas)

These are the clip space coordinates (assuming your viewport setting matches the texture size (the default)

```
                        +1,+1
  +-------+-------+-------+
  |       |       |       |
  |       |       |       |
  |       |       |       |
  +-------+-------+-------+
  |       |       |       |
  |       |       |       |
  |       |       |       |
  +-------+-------+-------+
-1, -1,
```

Looking further, the coordinates of each texel are

```
  clipSpace = (texelPosition + 0.5) / textureSize * 2 - 1


                        +1,+1
  +-------+-------+-------+     
  |       |       |       |   
  |   d   |   e   |   f   |    f = +0.666..., +0.5
  |       |       |       |    e =  0       , +0.5
  +-------+-------+-------+    d = -0.666..., +0.5
  |       |       |       |    c = +0.666..., -0.5
  |   a   |   b   |   c   |    b =  0       , -0.5
  |       |       |       |    a = -0.666..., -0.5
  +-------+-------+-------+
-1, -1,
```

(Compare [the spec on rasterization], which specifies the pixels center as the relevant points:

> Fragments are associated with pixel centers. That is, all the points with coordinates `C`, where `fract(C) = vector2(0.5, 0.5)` in the framebuffer space, enclosed into the polygon, are included.

So, assuming your depth texture covers the entire clip space then

```
   vec2f size = textureDimensions(depth_buffer, 0);
   vec2f clip_space = (vec2f(gid.xy) + 0.5) / size * 2.0 - 1.0;
```

whether or not you flip Y is up to you. There's no inherent mapping from invocation ids to anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While your formula seems to be correct, the answer unfortunately doesn't help me understand why that is :/ For example, in clip space, when a triangle is rasterized. when is the bottom-left pixel shaded? If the triangle covers (-1, -1) or when it covers (-0.666, -0.5)? Links to relevant sections of the spec would be appreciated as well.

Comment: it's when the center of the pixel (-0.666, -0.5) is inside the triangle. Example: https://jsgist.org/?src=a03e1b565cd1549d9e43bd9397533351

Comment: Note: [the spec covers this under Polygon Rasteriation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webgpu/#polygon-rasterization) but it's very spec like

Comment: Thanks for the link to the specs! I took the liberty and added the relevant section to your answer. I hope that was ok.